# How to mock and write unit test for try and catch block using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, resttemplate

In below example i am trying to test both catch and try block using mockito. And also when the CustomException is raised then i want to call the method with second host. Thank you.

```java
private static void getDetails()
{
    final String host1 = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employee/id";
   
    final String host2 = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/student/id";

     
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = null;
    try {
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(host1, String.class);
    } catch(CustomException customException) {
       String result = restTemplate.getForObject(host2, String.class);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what's your problem? do you want to know how to test this using mockito?

Comment: I want to test catch block when the exception is thrown.

Comment: I've added a sample answer below. I think that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to have `restTemplate` being passed to that method as an arg.

(If yes, then)

Using `org.mockito.Mockito -> mock()` you can mock like below,

```
RestTemplate restTemplateMock = mock(RestTemplate.class);
when(restTemplateMock.getForObject(host1)).thenThrow(CustomException.class);
```

Pass this mock object to your method and it will throw exception inside try.

Update: Sample test cases for your ref.

```
@Test
public void testGetDetails()
{
  RestTemplate restTemplateMock = mock(RestTemplate.class);
  when(restTemplateMock.getForObject(host1)).thenReturn(SOME_STRING);
  String result = //call your method
  assertThat(result).isEqualTo(SOME_STRING);
}

@Test
public void testGetDetailsUsesOtherHostWhenExceptionIsThrown()
{
  RestTemplate restTemplateMock = mock(RestTemplate.class);
  when(restTemplateMock.getForObject(host1)).thenThrow(CustomException.class);
  when(restTemplateMock.getForObject(host2)).thenReturn(SOME_STRING);
  String result = //call your method
  assertThat(result).isEqualTo(SOME_STRING);
}
```

When you in need to use same mock object,

```
RestTemplate myRestTemplateMock = mock(RestTemplate.class);

@Test
public void testGetDetails()
{
  when(myRestTemplateMock.getForObject(host1)).thenReturn(SOME_STRING);
  String result = //call your method
  assertThat(result).isEqualTo(SOME_STRING);
}

@Test
public void testGetDetailsUsesOtherHostWhenExceptionIsThrown()
{ 
  
  when(myRestTemplateMock.getForObject(host1)).
                                  thenThrow(CustomException.class);
  when(myRestTemplateMock.getForObject(host2)).thenReturn(SOME_STRING);
  String result = //call your method
  assertThat(result).isEqualTo(SOME_STRING);
}
```

Comment: I would like to know, how to test above method when there is no exception and when the exception is thrown. I want to write unit tests in both cases. Can you please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to use same mock resttemplate object for both test cases and also can we mock that exception in init() method.

Comment: Usually the object state is maintained once it is initialized with what we instruct (when->then) so we cannot use same object, may be you can declare the restTemplate at class level and define them under each test case separately

Comment: I have some properties which are initialized in init method and resttemplated object mocked in class level. So i am trying to reuse it. In any case possible to reuse existing mock object then it will helpful.

Comment: Yes, you can override the mock injection.. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sure i will try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216519/discussion-between-netaji-and-sabareesh-muralidharan).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, First of all, your original method needs to be like below. (since normal practice is we don't test private methods and if you need a static method to be tested you need something more than Mockito (PowerMock))

```
public class Example {

    @Autowired
    public RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public  String restTemplateTest()
    {
        final String host1 = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employee/id";

        final String host2 = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/student/id";

        String result;
        try {
             result = restTemplate.getForObject(host1, String.class);
        } catch(CustomException customException) {
             result = restTemplate.getForObject(host2, String.class);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Below is the sample test for the above method.

```
    public class ExampleTest {
    
       @Mock
       private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
       @InjectMocks
       private Example testExample;
    
       @BeforeEach
       public void setUp()
       {
           MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       }
    
        @Test
        public void restTemplateTest() {
    
            Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(Mockito.eq("http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employee/id"), Mockito.eq(String.class)))
                    .thenThrow(CustomException.class);
    
            Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(Mockito.eq("http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/student/id"), Mockito.eq(String.class)))
                    .thenReturn("expected");
    
            testExample.restTemplateTest();
    
            // if exception thrown , then rest template mock will invoke 2 times, otherwise
            // 1
            Mockito.verify(restTemplate, Mockito.times(2)).getForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(String.class));
    
        }

}
```

Below is the way to test when no Exception occurs scenario.

```
@Test
public void restTemplateTest_when_no_exception() {

    Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(Mockito.eq("http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employee/id"), Mockito.eq(String.class)))
            .thenReturn("expectedString");

    String actual = testExample.restTemplateTest();

    // if exception not thrown , then rest template mock will invoke 1 times, otherwise
    // 1
    Mockito.verify(restTemplate, Mockito.times(1)).getForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(String.class));

    Assert.assertEquals("expectedString",actual);
}
```

Comment: I would like to know, how to test above method when there is no exception and when the exception is thrown. I want to write unit tests in both cases. Can you please suggest me. Thank you.